# Steam's Download speed is very low

Tags: 12.10, downloads, steam

When using Ubuntu (I'm using 12.10) i get download speeds of about 0 when downloading through steam.
If I pause the download then resume, it goes up to normal, then slowly goes back down to 0. This does not happen in windows.

Comment: What Game are you downloadung ? Sometimes Steamservers are just overload.

Answer (score 0):

This happens on Windows too. Its from the steam servers being flooded by downloading the same thing. Its not an Ubuntu bug. Try changing the location settings and check if they are right and just be patient.

It DOES happen in Windows because it happens to me.  Its a application issue, it's not localised to any OS.  Its the steam servers being flooded from the same download, or just the servers getting throttled.

It doesnt seem like your internet is the issue, but it could be cutting in and out but I honestly doubt it.